# Converting raw text to usable object

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

In Python and with Pandas, I'm scraping data from a website into a dataframe and I use the dataframe's entries as the input of another function, call it f. One such entry, call it a1, is the text "Boston" (but without the quotes) and has unicode type. The crux of the problem is where the function does something like `f(x)=[Stuff].str.contains(x)`

Running `f("Boston")` works fine, but running `f(a1)` or `f(str(a1))` gives an error. I feel like I should easily be able to convert a1 into something that the function f can read, but I can't seem to figure it out.

What is also odd is that the two commands

```
print str(a1), type(str(a1))
print "Boston", type("Boston")
```

give identical outputs, but "Boston" works as an input for f while str(a1) does not.

Comment: unicode, as I said...

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I basically try df[df['RowName'].str.contains(x)].values, where df is a dataframe unrelated to the one that a1 is in. When x=a1 or str(a1), what returns is "[ ]", but when x="Boston", I get "[value1, value2, ...]", as it is supposed to do.